# Book about planning computer network

Tags: networking, infrastructure

I'm looking for a book dealing with creation (building, planning, implementing, ... don't know the right word in English) of company computer network (about 1 to few hundreds computers with a few servers, printers).

The book should cover various design decisions, hardware (choices based on performance needed for network), cabling, topology, budgeting, choice of operating systems, virtualization, firewalls...
There need not to be described network protocols and internals of operating systems (this is in another literature)
I prefer it to be up-to-date.

EDIT: The book should concentrate on the management and business thing of building network, not the technical (this is what I already know).

I wouldn't have asked, but I can't find this book in English.

Comment: What you are looking for is a library or bookstore, not a single book, I fear. In other words, I doubt there is one book covering all these topics in a reasonable way.

Comment: _Book about planning computer network_ and then you are saying _There need not to be described network protocols_ . I am afraid you can't do that.

Comment: I have seen such a book few years ago in another language. I don't see a reason why it couldn't be written in main world language from the point of view of a man who has built several middle-size company networks.

Comment: @user It only says that the main scope of the book should be designing (building) the network.

Comment: A book on management and business of networks, but not technical? I'm thinking you're either looking for a specific book title or there's a problem with the language barrier here. If you know of the other book, you might want to look it up again and find the author; it may be a translation. I don't know of anything fitting the specification you're looking for.

Comment: @Xralf It isn't "only a few bosses ruling serverfault", this question generated 3 close votes, 2 flags, and 1 moderator all agreeing. Except for the mod, that's the StackExchange accepted standard for 'close it'.

Comment: sysadmin1138 OK, the question could be closed. But why so soon? Why not to wait a few days more to give chance to answer and then close? The unsatisfied bored nerds here can just ignore the question they don't like.

Comment: @sysadmin1138 And why the tag `books` exist here? http://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/book What's so bad on my question in opposite to other questions tagged `books`?

Answer (score 1):

When you are looking more for the organizational side of running an IT organization, I highly recommend "[The Practice of System and Network Administration](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0321492668)" by Limoncelli et al.

Comment: Indeed! Just for completeness I would add "[Analytical Network and System Administration: Managing Human-Computer Systems](http://www.amazon.com/Analytical-Network-System-Administration-Human-Computer/dp/0470861002)"

Comment: @SvenW I was reading a table of contents but don't have a feeling that the goal of the book is to build a computer network of some company and design decisions that play important role. But your book is closest to my needs from the others answers.

Answer (score 0):

Like [SvenW](https://serverfault.com/users/8897/svenw) wrote you need a bookstore. You are asking for a book to cover some semesters in College and then some. "[Patterns in Network Architecture](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0132252422)" comes to mind, the books by [Stallings](http://williamstallings.com/) too and even "[Internet Routing Architectures](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/157870233X)".

I think it is best to try to think what you are going to build (or are assigned to maintain) and break it down in pieces that you can study separately. Then start from an introductory tile from say O'Reilly and hand around places like ServerFault, sage-members and / or LOPSA and while you are reading stuff and gaining experience by trying it out, ask more specific questions that can help you out.

I think you will find the "[Short Topics in System Administration](http://www.sage.org/pubs/short_topics.html)" by USENIX/SAGE interesting too.

Comment: No, I'm not looking a book that covers some semesters. I have some semesters behind me. The book should concentrate on the management and business thing of building network, not the technical (this is what I already know).

Comment: The "Short Topics in System Administration" could be helpful, though this is on password which I don't know and seems to be only slides?

Comment: You have to be a member of USENIX and SAGE to access these. Sorry if it was not clear.